# How to display dynamic range of data from another sheet, but while transforming one column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [sheet of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lG-iKRqoZ3BmBE58Uiy6C79hlDqSoCVxD1QVX-05Eyg/edit?usp=sharing) in the form:

```
Date           Val
2015-08-05     10
2015-08-09     13
2015-08-14     4
```

I am trying to display this data in other cell such that it looks like this:

```
Date           Val
2015-08        10
2015-08        13
2015-08         4
```

I do not want to use a text() function that transforms `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-mm` and then drag that down column A. I want all of the data to be dynamically populated such that adding new columns to the source sheet causes the other sheet to update automatically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you don't need to change the data at all, just change the presentation of the data, i.e., formatting. Select column A, go to Format -> Number -> More formats -> More data and time formats, and set the desired format there:

[image: format]

New date/time data added to Column A will automatically be shown as above.

Comment: This does not actually change the value of the cells, which is what I want to do. However, I cross-posted in the Google Docs Help Forum and found an answer there: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/9mmcOx5SlVM/7_1ORlvlygYJ

Answer (score 0):

Seems OP was happy with response from [Kishan](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/9mmcOx5SlVM/7_1ORlvlygYJ):

> =query('source data'!A2:B,"select A,B format A 'yyyy-mm'",0)